# @Autowire failure for JPA Repository in multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have a 3 module maven project, Model, Service and Web.  In Model I am defining JPARepositories and my @entity classes. I actually have 2 entity managers and 2 transaction managers in the Model project so I can connect to multiple databases (I dont need distributed transactions).

But I am getting errors on the injection of a JPARepository in my service  layer.

> No qualifying bean of type
>   [com.mycompany.rd.repository.misf.ProjectRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=projectRepository)}

In web.xml I have this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      classpath:/appContext-demo.xml,
      classpath*:/appContext-services.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

appContext-demo.xml is in the web module and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">



    <bean id="appInitializer" class="com.mycompany.rd.web.misf.demo.AppInitializer" 
          init-method="init"/>  
</beans>
```

In my service module, appContext-services.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">



    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.rd.service"/>

    <!-- Load app context for persistence from base-model project -->
    <import resource="classpath*:/appContext-model.xml" />
```

In my Model layer, I have this for appContext-model.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd         
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd         
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd         
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd  
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd        
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />

    <import resource="persistence.xml" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.rd.model,com.mycompany.rd.repository" />

    <bean id="grapsDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx" />
        <property name="username" value="xxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxx" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="grapsTM">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="grapsEM" />
        <qualifier value="graps" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grapsEM"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="grapsDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="graps-jpa" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="grapsTM" />

    <bean id="xpDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">        
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx;"/>
        <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="xpTM">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="xpEM" />
        <qualifier value="xp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="xpEM"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="xpDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="xp-jpa" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="xpTM"  />


    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.rd.repository.misf" entity-manager-factory-ref="xpEM" transaction-manager-ref="xpTM"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.rd.repository.graps" entity-manager-factory-ref="grapsEM" transaction-manager-ref="grapsTM" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />



</beans>
```

I am importing the persistence.xml file in appContext-model.xml and this looks as  below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="graps-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">        
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>                
        <class>com.mycompany.rd.model.graps.PrProject</class>       
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>        
        <properties>            
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle"/>            
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>            
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>        
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>  

    <persistence-unit name="xp-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">        
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>                
        <class>com.mycompany.rd.model.graps.PrProject</class>       
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>        
        <properties>            
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="SQLServer"/>            
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>            
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>        
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My service class raising the error is @Autowired with a JPARepository from the Model module:

```
package com.mycompany.rd.service.misf;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.mycompany.rd.model.misf.Project;
import com.mycompany.rd.repository.misf.ProjectRepository;

@Service
public class ProjectService {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectService.class);

    @Autowired  @Qualifier("projectRepository")
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Transactional(value="xp")
    public Project saveProject(Project project) {
        return projectRepository.save(project);
    }

    @Transactional(value="xp")
    public void deleteProject(Long projectSK) {
        logger.debug("Deleting project with id: " + projectSK);                 
        Project deleted = projectRepository.findOne(projectSK);
        if (deleted == null) {            
            logger.debug("No project found with id: " + projectSK);            
        } else {
            projectRepository.delete(projectSK);
            logger.debug("Project deleted with id: " + projectSK);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(value="xp")
    public Project getProjectByProjectSk(Long projectSK) {
        return projectRepository.findOne(projectSK);
    }

    @Transactional(value="xp")
    public List<Project> getAllProjects() {
        return (List<Project>) projectRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional(value="xp")
    public Page<Project> getAllProjects(Pageable pageable) {
        return projectRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Transactional(value="xp")
    public List<Project> getProjectsByDisease(String disease) {
        return projectRepository.findByDisease(disease);
    }


}
```

And the repository in my model Module is defined as this:

```
package com.mycompany.rd.repository.misf;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.mycompany.rd.model.misf.Project;

@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Project, Long>{


    @Query("select p from Project p where p.disease = :disease order by p.projectNm")
    public List<Project> findByDisease(
            @Param("disease") String disease);

    public Page<Project> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Driving me insane.  Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Is this a new project or an existing one that's stopped working? What happens if you drop the qualifier on the field?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue was because I was importing persistence.xml into an appContext.xml file.  The persistence.xml file I have been told is not a valid spring config file.  i.e. it uses the persistence xlmns in my instance, and I am importing into a beans xmlns file.

I am now doing this (thanks SO!) rather than an "import resource" - and my beans are now being wired it seems.

```
<bean id="pum"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try put all necessary package into component-scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.rd.service,com.mycompany.rd.repository "/>
```

Maybe you could use annotation @Component